# Multiple ads load in my unity3d android game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I got a unity 3d android game, and into I load some ads. 
So one of the ads is  a banner, the problem is that it appears more than one banner (no idea why :( ). they all stacked up on top of each other, looks like it called.

I load the ads like this.

```
void Start () {
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    AirScript.StartAirBanner360Ad();
    #endif
```

maybe I need to stop it once the ad load (I don't know how to do that) or just say it that i want one at the same time, and if other comes close that is open it.

I need help guys!!!

this is the guide that my company give me to load the ads. GUIDE [here](http://manage.airpush.com/docs/index.php?title=Unity3D_Plugin_For_Bundle_2_SDK)!

THANKS GUYS!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add more than one banners, but you have to be careful about showing and hiding banners.

Be careful, don't show overlap banner at the time of banner showing. Otherwise, it may create problem or may be rejected by Android or iOS.

Comment: Thats the thing, i just add one banner but they all stacked up on top of each other

Comment: Which AdSences for banner view  you used ?

Comment: I use airpush banner360 http://manage.airpush.com/docs/index.php?title=Unity3D_Plugin_For_Bundle_2_SDK